# What is the usage of "leaking"?

Tags: phrase-usage

For example, "The faucet is leaking water." Is the word "water" using with leaking here okay or redundant ?

Comment: Just hook up to the waterpipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't told us what the faucet is hooked up to. If it is the kitchen sink, then you might just need to say "This faucet is leaking." But sometimes when we request service on a leaky kitchen or bathroom or other household faucet,  or even describe the things in a house, we might go ahead and be explicit and say "This faucet is leaking water" or "The kitchen sink leaks water."

If the faucet is hooked up to some other kind of system such as one that has chemicals, the faucet might not be leaking water. So you have the same situation, only in a different situation. You can be explicit if you want.

You don't always have to avoid redundancy, if that is also a concern of yours.

Comment: Thank you. By the way, what is difference between "a concern of yours" and "your concern." as above? Are they same?

Comment: One more question. You said "The kitchen sink leaks water.". How can a sink leak water, a hole in the sink or you mean the faucet in the sink leaks water?